# Why do I have to free 2D array twice to avoid memory leak?

Tags: c++

I am running into a memory leak problem when allocating a 2D array.
But I could not understand why the memory leaks.

My reasoning is that at Note A, I have already freed allocated memory, since `data_[0] == data_`, why do I have to do the free at Note B?

```
class Matrix {
public:
  Matrix(int r, int c) {
    this->rows = r;
    this->cols = c;
    data_ = new int*[r];
    for (int i = 0; i < r; i++) {
      data_[i] = new int[c];
    }
  }

  ~Matrix() {
    for (int i = 0; i < this->rows; i++) {
      delete [] data_[i]; // Note A；
    }
    delete[] data_; // Note B; <-- not doing this line will leak memory, but why?
  }
private:
  int rows;
  int cols;
  int **data_;
};
```

Comment: `data_` points to an array, which saves pointers. You only free the pointers saved in that array, but not free the array it self. For simplicity, why not just `new int [c][r]`, than you can just use `delete [] data_`.

Comment: You had 2 news (ok, so 1 + r) so you need 2 deletes (1 + r)

Comment: Thanks @psinonic12 and @John3136. I understand the issue better now.  I had the wrong impression that `data_ == data_[0]` are the same thing. In reality they are two arrays, they point to different addresses in the heap.

Comment: Learn about [containers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container) and the [C++ rule of five](https://cpppatterns.com/patterns/rule-of-five.html). You could actually find some open source matrix template somewhere, e.g. in [Boost](https://www.boost.org/). Compile your C++ code with a recent [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) compiler invoked as `g++ -Wall -Wextra -g` and use [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/) and [valgrind](https://valgrind.org/).

Comment: If allowed use also [static analyzer](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Static-Analyzer-Options.html) and [address sanitizer](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Instrumentation-Options.html) options of GCC.

Comment: thanks @BasileStarynkevitch, I am very new to C++ but will definitely give the tools you linked a shot.

Comment: A good book to read about memory management is [*the GC handbook*](https://gchandbook.org/), after having read some [operating system textbook](https://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~remzi/OSTEP/) and [*Introduction to algorithms*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Introduction_to_Algorithms)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you post there isn't really a 2D array, it's a 1D array-of-pointers (`data_`), and then you allocate a separate array-of-ints for each element of the first array (so `data_[0]` is an array of `c` ints, `data_[1]` is an array of `c` ints, and so on).

Given that, it's natural that you'll have to do one `delete[]` in your destructor for each `new` that you performed earlier in your constructor.

A graphical diagram of your memory allocations and how they point to each other might look like this (if `c==6` and you have set all of your arrays' integers to `0`):

[image: allocation diagram]

A real 2D array allocation would look like this:  `int * array2D = new int[6][8];`, but of course C++ only supports 2D arrays if the array-dimenions are compile-time constants, so that probably wouldn't solve the problem your `Matrix` class is meant to solve.

Comment: Thank you the distinction between the one 2D array and the many 1D arrays really resolved one of my long time misconception!

Answer (score 1):

When you have created 2D array (for example 3x3), you have created 1 array with 3 elements, where each element is pointer to separate array. So to clear memory for this matrix you need to clear 4 arrays (3 rows and 1 array containing pointers).
You can check how many times in your code you are calling new operator
it will be r+1 times

```
data_ = new int*[r];// 1 time
for (int i = 0; i < r; i++ {
  data_[i] = new T[c]; // r times
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Part I:**
The line `data_ = new int*[r];` allocates and default initializes a dynamic array of int* through new, so you would need to provide a corresponding `delete [] data_;` for this line.

**Part II:**
The line `data_[i] = new int[c];` dynamically allocates and default initializes an int array and then the pointer to that first element is returned and stored as the `data_[i]` element. So here again you would need a corresponding `delete [] data_[i];` to get rid of the memory leak.
So these were the reasons why you need two separate `delete []`. The process is as shown in the screenshot. Also note that the important thing is the default initialization. So the int array elements will not all have a value 0 as wrongly shown in the answer by @Jeremy Friesner.[image: screenshot1]

Comment: "A graphical diagram of your memory allocations and how they point to each other might look like this (if c==6 and all of your integers are set to 0)"

Comment: Yes, for your case it will be 0 but in the question the dynamically allocated int array is default  initialized.

Comment: The question is about new and delete, not about default initialization, so I glossed over that point to avoid distracting from the issue at hand.

Comment: Yeah but still technically there is a fault in your diagram.